# Iterating through a HashMap to find a key object that matches an outside object in Java

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I am quite new to coding in general and this may be a simple answer. I certainly hope that it is.
I am trying to iterate through a HashMap and compare the Key to an outside object of the same type. When I run the method, it is not showing me that the objects match even though their values are the same. The Point class is made up from 2 integers, an x and a y.
Here is my code:

```
for (HashMap.Entry<Point, Character> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Point point = new Point(0,0);
    point = entry.getKey();
    if(point == outsidePoint){
       //insert code here
    }
```

I know that at some time during the iteration that the *point* object is equal to the *outsidePoint* object, but it will not run the code inside the if statement.

Any help would be incredibly beneficial.

Comment: `==` is for reference equality. Use `equals()` to compare separate but equivalent objects.

Comment: You need to use `.equals`, not `==`, or -- even better -- you should just do the map lookup, just using `map.get(point)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, when you want to compare two different objects of the same type in java, you have to use .equals() instead of ==. So whole code is:

```
for (HashMap.Entry<Point, Character> entry : map.entrySet()) {
Point point = entry.getKey();
if(point.equals(outsidePoint)){
   //insert code here
}
```

You can also assign `entry.getKey()` to point directly, there is no need for `new Point()`.